# All Subscribers attributes vs. DE attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

When sending to a DE, do All Subs attributes get pulled in by default?

For example, DE and All Subs both have a record with the same Subscriber Key but DE has First Name 'Mike' whereas All Subs has First Name 'Joe'. I want the First Name to = 'Mike' but I'm getting First Name = 'Joe.'

How can I fix?

If I'm not using the All Subs list for anything but status verification at send time, can I just delete that All Subs attribute?

Comment: if the DE field name matches profile attributes and the DE has a value it should use the DE value first

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AttributeValue AMPScript function](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/) to pull the value of the first name directly from the Data Extension used for sending an email.

```
%%[
SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
]%%
Hello %%=v(@FirstName)=%%...
```